# php codeigniter insert query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my model insert query. No any error but it is not work. Can any one explain what was the problem with the code.

The query is :

```html
INSERT INTO `user_invite` (`invt_code`, `invt_time`, `email`, `biz_id`, `role_role_id`) 
VALUES ('IxKS0zgq6Dwv', '2017-10-02 09:27:38', 'test@gmail.com', '81', '3');
```

when I got my last query and manually run it is working correctly. above is my last query.

the problem with model my model is:
       public function adduser($sdata){

```
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $res = $this->db->insert('user_invite', $sdata);

    $this->db->trans_commit();

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return $res;

}
```

Comment: Is this code in loop?, what is in $sdata?

Comment: no it is not a loop. $data mean insert data as an associative array. above is the last query. Insert query manually work.

Comment: which db are u using ? if it's mysql, you need INNODB tables rather than MYISAM - check that ! and the second question - if this is the entire code in your function - why do you need transactions here ?

Comment: mysql and it is in InnoDB

Comment: here when user add a new user request for register in the application we save them in user_invite table. previousely it worked well

Comment: "Previously it worked well"... Well what is different now to "previuosly"?

Comment: Can you show me where is coming from $sdata?

Comment: I check if user already registered or not if he not register then send an invitation

Comment: $bizId = $this->session->userdata('businessId');
        $sdata['invt_code'] = $invtCode;
        $sdata['invt_time'] = $timeStamp;
        $sdata['email'] = $this->input->post('salesAssEmail');
        $sdata['biz_id'] = $bizId;
        $sdata['corporate_user_role_role_id'] = $this->input->post('userRole');

Comment: can you share the mysql schema of the table user_invite. There might be some issue in execution of the query. Do enable error logging as well

Comment: when I remove new condition it is work. I will check with condition.

Comment: can you explain why this happen, I get model function $isAlreadyRegistered = $this->Sales_assistant_model->isExist_C_userByEmail($sdata['email']);

Comment: if I comment that that insert query works

Comment: public function isExist_C_userByEmail($email){

        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->select('COUNT(email) AS email');

        $this->db->from('corporate_user');

        $this->db->where('email',$email);

        $this->db->where('status','1');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $row = $query->row();

            $count = $row->email;

        }

        return $count;
    }

Answer (score 0):

**$sdata** should be an array

**adduser.php** looks like this

```
public function adduser($sdata)
    {


        $this->db->trans_start();

        $res = $this->db->insert('user_invite', $sdata);

        $this->db->trans_commit();

        $this->db->trans_complete();

        return $res;
    }
```

**$sdata**

```
$sdata = array(
            'field' => 'some data',
            'field' => 'again some data and goes on' ,
        );
```

Comment: that function works when I comment this function call     public function isExist_C_userByEmail($email){

        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->select('COUNT(email) AS email');

        $this->db->from('corporate_user');

        $this->db->where('email',$email);

        $this->db->where('status','1');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $row = $query->row();

            $count = $row->email;

        }

        return $count;
    }

Comment: $isExist = $this->Sales_assistant_model->isUserExist($isUser);
            $isUserExistInC_user = $this->Sales_assistant_model->checkCuserIs($sdata['email'], $bizId);
             $isAlreadyRegistered = $this->Sales_assistant_model->isExist_C_userByEmail($sdata['email']);

Comment: after that condtion if ($isUserExistInC_user == 0) {
                //If user in the C-user table
                if($isAlreadyRegistered > 0){
                    $businessName = $this->Sales_assistant_model->getBizName($bizId);
                    $roleName = $this->Sales_assistant_model->getUserRolesByRoleId($sdata['corporate_user_role_role_id']);
                    $username = $this->Sales_assistant_model->get_C_userNameByEmail($sdata['email']);

Comment: }else{
                    if ($isExist == 0) {
                        $res = $this->Sales_assistant_model->adduser($sdata);

Comment: } else {
                        $status = 2;
                        $res_update = $this->Sales_assistant_model->updateUser_invite_rejectUser($sdata['email'], $bizId, $status);
                        $res = $this->Sales_assistant_model->adduser($sdata);   }
              }